# UserDir is disabled yet server still responds differently to /~root

Tags: root, mod-userdir

Using CentOS 6.5 I am trying to completely disable User Dir functionality so that /~ will not work at all. My httpd.config

```
UserDir disabled
```

and

```
#UserDir public_html
```

And also commented out

```
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
```

but when I browse my website, if I put `/~root` I get a message in Firefox:

> The connection was reset.

It should not treat `~root` any different than any other link that does not exist. I am using Magento so for any other link that does not exist Magento displays:

> Oops page not found

but for `~root` it seems like it is bypassing Magento and providing a different error.

Comment: The place to start looking is the webserver access_log and/or error_log files.

Comment: There is only 1 website on this server. When I look at my website specific logs I can see the other ~testhasgds that I am trying but not the ~root

Comment: When I look at the general access_log and error_log I do not see any entry with the ~root

Comment: The logs I am looking at are in etc/httpd/logs any other place that related logs can be?

Comment: Additional log files per virtual host can be specified in VirtualHost stanza's

Comment: No other log files have been configured under virtualhost. I also tried ErrorDocument 404 and ErrorDocument 403 in httpd.conf but that did not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Just tested and on my CentOS 6.5 books trying to access an /~root simply triggers a 404, odd...